# Copy data to another sheet without duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, conditional-statements, copy-paste

I have a main sheet (Sheet1) that has a database of products (name, reference, expiration date, status, ...).

My goal is to copy data to two sheets (Sheet3 & Sheet4) depending on a certain condition (the status of the products).

My code is run every time the Excel file is opened (because the statuses can change depending on the expiration date).
First time the file is opened, I get copied data as planned. The file is saved, then closed.
When I open the file and the code is executed another time, the same data is copied. Hence I get duplicates.

I added something to remove duplicates but the code runs slowly.

```vb
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range
Dim DuplicateValues As Range
Dim DuplicateValues2 As Range

Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("G2:G999999")

For Each Status In StatusCol
    
    If Sheet3.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet3.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status = "about to expire" Then Status.EntireRow.Copy PasteCell
    
    If Sheet4.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet4.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet4.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status = "expired" Then Status.EntireRow.Copy PasteCell
    
Next Status

Set DuplicateValues = Sheet3.Range("A1:XFD1048576")
Set DuplicateValues2 = Sheet4.Range("A1:XFD1048576")

DuplicateValues.removeduplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
DuplicateValues2.removeduplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

I tried to add a condition that verifies whether the data already exists in the sheet where the copy is to be made; so only new data is copied.

```vb
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim Code As Range
Dim CodeCol As Range
Dim Code2 As Range
Dim CodeCol2 As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range
Dim DuplicateValues As Range
Dim DuplicateValues2 As Range

Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("G2:G999999")
Set CodeCol = Sheet3.Range("D2:D999999")
Set CodeCol2 = Sheet4.Range("D2:D999999")

For Each Status In StatusCol
    
    If Sheet3.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet3.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status = "about to expire" Then
        
        With CodeCol
            Set Code = .Find(What:=CodeCol.Value, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Code Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Status.EntireRow.Copy PasteCell
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
    If Sheet4.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet4.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet4.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status = "expired" Then
        
        With CodeCol2
            Set Code2 = .Find(What:=CodeCol2.Value, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Code2 Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Status.EntireRow.Copy PasteCell
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
Next Status

End Sub
```

I receive no error, but the copy doesn't occur.

Comment: One thing that could help is, if formatting is of no concern, `destination.Value = source.Value` when implanting data in other sheets.  Specific to `Code2`, does this state that you're searching for the entire value of the column within the sheet (`What:=CodeCol2.Value`)?  I would think you'd be able to narrow down where *something* expected is not occuring by stepping through (F8), then we can help correct that specific point... my first guess would be the `Find` and the subsequent `If` statement.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the `Find` or subsequent `If` statement are causing the issues, I would something similar to the below may help:

```
dim destinationSheet as worksheet
select case Status.Value
    Case "about to expire"
        set destinationSheet = Sheet2
    Case ""
        set destinationSheet = Sheet3
end select
dim uniqueID as string
uniqueID = Status.Offset(,-3).Value 'Arbitrary -3 offset to the cell in the row with the ID to be found
dim uniqueIDCheck as range
set uniqueIDCheck = destinationSheet.Find(uniqueID)
if uniqueIDCheck is nothing then
    dim destinationLastRow as long
    destinationLastRow = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row
    destinationSheet.Rows(destinationLastRow+1).Value = Status.EntireRow.Value
end if
```

Comment: Note that this approach would fit into your use of `Status`, but relies on a single `Find` and determines the destination sheet in a `Case`.